# Recover GPT Hard Disk files on Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, windows, partition

My friends 2008(ish) era macbook pro died recently but the SATA HDD is fine, I have removed it and plugged it into a Windows 7 machine. I can see in Paragon Partition Manager that the drive is a GPT Hard Disk, how do i go about viewing the files on Windows? The PC I have connected it to has dualboot ubuntu, would it be easier to access the files from linux? Any freeware suggestions? I have tried googling for a few tutorials but these tend to focus on a dead HDD.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GTP isn't the issue, it's the HFS+ (aka Mac OS Extended) volume inside it; in order to read that, you need HFS+ drivers for Windows (or Linux or whatever). Paragon sells a [driver for this](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/), or you could use the drivers from Apple's Boot Camp software. I can't vouch for their authenticity, but I found downloads claiming to be just the HFS+ parts of Boot Camp at [MacRumors.com](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1368010) and [MacBreaker.com](http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/02/access-mac-os-x-partition-from-windows.html).